# Cannot import tensorflow to python 3.5 (imports successfully in 2.7)

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

Please help

I am able to import tensortflow when in python 2.7 but when importing into python 3.5, it fails with: **ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'**.

the {pip show tensorflow} command shows the following:

Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: setuptools, astor, protobuf, gast, enum34, six, wheel, absl-py, backports.weakref, tensorboard, termcolor, numpy, grpcio, mock
Required-by:

Comment: `pip3 install tensorflow` will install tensorflow package to the python3 directory.
If it import in python2.7 it's because you probably did `pip install tensorflow` which installed it to python2.7 directory-

Comment: Note the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` in the `pip show`, telling you that it is showing a version installed for python 2.7 not for 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to install tensorflow:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

or with anaconda:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

Answer (score -1):

for Anaconda 2019.03 with Python 3.7 version

for CPU

create command:

conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow

activate command:

conda activate tensorflow_env

Import command:

(tensorflow_env) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >
> > > print(tf.**version**)

for GPU

create command:

conda create -n tensorflow_gpuenv tensorflow-gpu

activate command:

conda activate tensorflow_gpuenv

Import command:

(tensorflow_gpuenv) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >
> > > print(tf.**version**)